# How to execute a Java application in a cloud computing or in a supercomputer

Tags: java, eclipse, cloud

I developed an application in java (eclipse) to parse XML files (about 400), store them in a database object (neodatis) and then calculate the similarity between these files. But when running my pc is a quick plow.
Some advise me to move to cloud computing (Windows Azure, Amazon EC2, Google App Engine etc).
What do you think? I also think supercomputer!
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Comparing 400 XML documents is certainly not supercomputer territory. Perhaps a cluster would be good, at a push, but really a desktop should be able to do this absolutely fine. If I were you I would look at optimising your code first, so it works for 400 documents on a desktop. It is possible!

One possible cause of inefficiency might be that you are performing N<sup>2</sup> compare operations, which doesn't scale well. Perhaps you could look at some graph / clustering algorithms to cut down the number of comparisons you need to make.

Comment: Just to support @Joe: Don't be affraid if a computation takes several hours. I can imagine that this is a one time task, and moving stuff like this to the cloud when you are not experienced would quickly take multiple days. So even if your computation takes a few days you would still be quicker. Maybe add some kind of progress report so you can estimate how quickly it progresses.

Comment: It's true. Also, there are few things more satisfying than seeing your code crunching through data!

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But I am comparing the documents as a comparaison of trees,  with sometimes 50 paths per tree!!! It took 8h for one comparaison (two trees) , so for 400 trees it's impossible.
What can I do for optimising my code?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Well you can try splitting trees into sub-trees for comparison, or controlling back-tracking in your tree traversal, or creating partial hashes of various bits for speedy comparison... Often there is a trade-off between accuracy and speed. If you don't want an absolutely exact number, you can take some heuristic short-cuts.

Comment: Hi, 
thanks for your answer..but I have to use the absolute exact number, so I am trying to find a solution in the  grid computing!!